# Cassandra pod crashing as ERROR during truncate, Requested permits(0) must be positive

Tags: cassandra

My opensource cassandra pod running on k8s frequently gets into crashloopbackoff. It says about permit issue shared below the logs. It appears to be related with concurrency issue. Can anyone help  me or know what parameter I need to tweak in cassandra spec or charts to get it resolved.

```
CassandraDaemon.java:822 - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.TruncateException: Error during truncate: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested permits (0) must be positive
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement.executeLocally(TruncateStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.executeInternal(QueryProcessor.java:323)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.clearAllEstimates(SystemKeyspace.java:1337)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.cleanupSizeEstimates(StorageService.java:3908)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:353)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:676)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:800)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested permits (0) must be positive
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2329)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2276)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.truncateBlocking(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2256)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement.executeLocally(TruncateStatement.java:92)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested permits (0) must be positive
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:189)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.checkPermits(RateLimiter.java:430)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.reserve(RateLimiter.java:285)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.acquire(RateLimiter.java:273)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshotWithoutFlush(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1801)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshot(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1981)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshot(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1957)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshot(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1945)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$4.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2242)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2325)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```